# OpenPyXL - Iterate over rows in reverse order, from ws.max_row to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Using OpenPyXL, I wish to delete empty rows in the worksheet, and believe the best approach to be to begin at the bottom with `max_row` and iterate up to the top.

I understand that to iterate over a collection in reverse order, use reversed():

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
for i in reversed(a):
    print(i)
```

However, I am unsure how to translate this to the OpenPyXL rows collection.

At the moment, I have this but I am wondering if there is a better way to proceed using `reversed()`

```
for i in range(ws.max_row, 1, -1):
    print(i)
```

Important Note: I am identifying and deleting empty rows and wonder how that will affect iterating up through a rows **collection** ?

Comment: You can use `reversed`; deleting rows while iterating over them will have unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rows = list(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row)
if needReversed:
    rows = reversed(rows)
for row in rows:
    print(row[0].value)
```

Comment: This is great since I can still take advantage of `min_col` and `max_col` in the `iter_rows` function call and then use `for` looping on the properly sub-sectioned rows. You did forget a `)` though.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so here's how I did this. Despite author Charlie Clark's suggestion to use `reversed`, I still haven't identified the syntax to use that method.

However, this worked fine:

```
print('BEGIN: sheet.max_row: ' + str(sheet.max_row))

for rr in range(sheet.max_row, 1, -1):
    hasData = False
    for cc in range(1, sheet.max_column+1):
        tmp = AlphaFromIndex(cc)
        ref = str(tmp) + str(rr)
        val = sheet[ref].value
        if val is not None: hasData = True
    if not hasData:
        print('Row: ' + str(rr) + ' -- Deleting row: ' + str(rr))
        sheet.delete_rows(rr, 1)
    else:
        print('Row: ' + str(rr) + ' of (' +str(sheet.max_row)+')')

print('END: sheet.max_row: ' + str(sheet.max_row))

def AlphaFromIndex(num):
    ab = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    return ab[num - 1]
```

### * BUT *

The main take away from this exercise is that OpenPyXL will not update formulas in rows below any deleted rows. So, deleting blank rows is a bad idea in OpenPyXL *as any pre-existing formulas will now refer to the wrong rows.*