# Function will delete only Odd numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Basically i have this function which should delete all rows from a excel file if cell.value is in asin_txt, but for some reason it would only work right when this list contains an even number of items, if the number is odd, it would delete odd number-1 (eg: 10-1 = deletes only 9 rows)

Also tried `sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row, 1)` instead of `sheet.delete_rows(row[1].row, 1)`, and if the number of items is 10, it will delete only 8 rows.

This should delete all corresponding rows if cell.value is in asin_txt

```
import openpyxl
path = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\TEST-SCALA.xlsx'
data = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = data['ONE1']

def get_asins():
    asin_txt = asin_inputbox.get(0.1, END)
    asin_txt = asin_txt.split()
    return asin_txt

def remove(sheet, row):
    asin_txt = get_asins()
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value != None and cell.value in asin_txt:
            sheet.delete_rows(row[1].row, 1)
            print(cell.value, ' deleted')


for row in sheet:
     remove(sheet, row)
asin_txt = get_asins()
print(asin_txt)
data.save(path)
```

Comment: I don't know Python but when deleting rows in Excel, you need to know that everytime a row is deleted, the row number changes because all data goes up 1 row. To avoid this, it's easier to delete from last to first, (10 to 1 as example) instead of first to last because it may cause weird results. Have you tried looping backwards?

Comment: Can you pls share the full code including opening the file in python? Assuming you are opening the file with openpyxl and moving the information to ````data````

Comment: Code UPDATED :  Maybe the problem is with get_asins() , I have tested separately the code without get_asins() , and I have inserted manually  items in asin_txt, and it worked OK

Comment: Hi - The problem is not odd vs. even. It is, as mentioned by @Firefox..., because of your iteration starting from first row to last. You need to go in reverse and it should work. As the code for inputbox was not available, I used a list for ````asin_txt````.  In your main code, replace ````for row in sheet:```` with below code ````rows = list(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row))
rows = reversed(rows)
for row in rows:
    remove(sheet, row)```` and it should work. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I borrowed the code for going through rows in reverse from here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866161/openpyxl-iterate-over-rows-in-reverse-order-from-ws-max-row-to-1)

Comment: @Redox , I have used this version but it wasn't working because I was using ```for row in sheet: ```  instead of  ```for row in rows: ``` .  You're example works great, Thank you!